# Popup form closing wihtout page refresh when submitted

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to get this form to close when the button is pressed without the page refreshing. Someone else will then place in the Ajax code. 
This form is a pop up, so the pop up needs to close. Currently I can click the button without refresh, but I need the popup box to close. 
I have found various using Ajax etc, but as said someone else will be putting in the Ajax after I can get it to close. 
This is the form code

```
<div id="contact_form">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rangeStart1">Range Start</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rangeStart3" placeholder="Range Start">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rangeFinish1">Range Finish</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rangeFinish3" placeholder="Range Finish">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the function (which I found here on Stackoverflow)

```
 function sendContactForm(){
 $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
     sendContactForm();
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: seems that you misssed the closing of function.

Comment: why is it recursive ? where are you calling the function ?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of gigging o the html, and this is wha made i work for me,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form-1').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).prop('action')+'?' + $(this).serialize());
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#form-2').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).prop('action')+'?' + $(this).serialize());
        $('#myModal-1').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Thanks to Upendrasinh Jadeja for guidance